# Using Python 3 in Azure Functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-functions

I'm aiming to get some Python 3 code running as an Azure Function, but I can't get Python 3 to work (I realize python support in Azure Functions is still experimental).

Here's what I've tried.

1. Create a new Function App - I've given it a name, and left everything else as default.
2. Created a Python HttpTrigger function, with the following code:

   ```
   import sys
   import os

   response = open(os.environ['res'], 'w')
   response.write(sys.version)
   response.close()
   ```

Running this function gives an output of `"2.7.8 (default, Jun 30 2014, 16:03:49) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]"` as expected, because 2.7.8 is the default version of python that is installed in the Azure Functions environment.

3. I then uploaded the embeddable version of python 3.6.1 to d:\site\tools using Kudu, as described in [this Azure wiki page](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki/Using-a-custom-version-of-Python)

When I run the function again, I get the output `"3.6.1 (v3.6.1:69c0db5, Mar 21 2017, 17:54:52) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]"` - so all is good there.

However, if I restart the function app (or just leave it alone for a while so it gets shut down) then everything breaks. Running the function gives:

```
{
  "id": "dd7c4462-0d73-49e0-8779-67b15a9bba82",
  "requestId": "ff553805-501d-4ea6-93f6-7bd6fa445a37",
  "statusCode": 500,
  "errorCode": 0,
  "message": "Exception while executing function: Functions.HttpTriggerPython31 -> "
}
```

The logs show:

```
2017-11-09T17:37:04.988 Function started (Id=941e5bef-e5e0-4604-8533-dd2a5fcaddf0)
2017-11-09T17:37:05.348 Exception while executing function: Functions.HttpTriggerPython31. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: .
2017-11-09T17:37:05.364 Function completed (Failure, Id=941e5bef-e5e0-4604-8533-dd2a5fcaddf0, Duration=363ms)
```

If I delete the python files from d:\site\tools, then then function starts working again, but runs with v2.7.8

However, I can get python 3.x to run from the Kudu console:

```
D:\home\site\tools>python -c "import sys;print(sys.version)"
3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed8, Oct  3 2017, 17:26:49) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]
```

Does anyone else have Python 3 successfully running in Azure Functions? What do I need to do to get it working?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For the moment there is an open issue :

- [Add ability to change Python version](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/519)

But as a workaround, everything is explain [here](https://github.com/meken/azure-functions-python) (All credits to the author: [Murat Eken](https://github.com/meken))

1. Create your function.
2. Installing a site extension with an alternative Python version and configuring the handler mapping to use that installation by default..

   2.1. Go to "Platform features > All Settings > Extensions > + Add

   2.2. Install the "Python 3.6.2 x86" extension.

   2.3. Go to "Platform features > Applications Settings

   2.4. Add an handler mapping:
   extension : fastCgi
   processor: D:\home\python362x86\python.exe
   arguments: D:\home\python362x86\wfastcgi.py

[image: Azure Function - Handler mapping to use a specific python version]

2.5 Add an application setting called WEBSITE_USE_PLACEHOLDER and set its value to 0. This is necessary to work around [an Azure Functions issue that causes the Python extension to stop working after the function app is unloaded](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c130decf-a4e5-493c-9c5e-af62828b6a80/python-3-function-stops-working-after-a-while?forum=AzureFunctions).

2.6. Save your app settings.

Here is the output of my function
`"3.6.2 (v3.6.2:5fd33b5, Jul  8 2017, 04:14:34) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]"`

you can automate these step using an [ARM Template](https://github.com/meken/azure-functions-python/blob/master/azuredeploy.json), here are the interesting part of the template:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    //...
  },
  "variables": {
    // ...
  },
  "resources": [
    // ...
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
      // ...
      "kind": "functionapp",
      "properties": {
        // ...
        "siteConfig": {
          "handlerMappings": [{
            "arguments": "D:\\home\\python362x86\\wfastcgi.py",
            "extension": "fastCgi",
            "scriptProcessor": "D:\\home\\python362x86\\python.exe"
          }]
          // ...
        },
        "resources": [{
          "name": "python362x86",
          "type": "siteextensions",
          "apiVersion": "2016-08-01",
          "properties": {}
          // ...
        }]
        // ...
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Actually this hasn't quite fixed the problem. After installing the Python extension and setting the fastcgi handler, the script runs. But when I leave it for a few hours, it's back to the 500 response. Restarting the function app doesn't fix this, but after changing the App Settings (e.g. adding a setting called DUMMY) the script starts working again.

Comment: I guess we need to check the resolution of this issue: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/519

Comment: As a workaround to prevent the script breaking after a few hours, it was necessary to add the Application Setting WEBSITE_USE_PLACEHOLDER=0

See https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c130decf-a4e5-493c-9c5e-af62828b6a80/python-3-function-stops-working-after-a-while?forum=AzureFunctions

Comment: Good to know, nice :-)

Comment: This no longer works with the new Function App experience in Azure Portal.  "Platform Features" is gone and there doesn't seem to be a UI-based way to set custom handlers.  Anyone know how to do this with the new experience?