# Azure Functions: Executing python class

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Before venturing into Azure function I wanted to ask. I have python class which calls 4 others class and do some data extraction.

Is it possible to execute this class and thereby the other 4 classes through Azure function?

I am aware that a single python code can be executed but is it possible to execute a collection of files?

Comment: if you push your 4 classes to the execution directory, it will be fine

Comment: So I will be executing the function through ADFv2 through the HTTP trigger. Now can I put multiple run.py in the function and get different function URL for each one of them so that I can be able to execute it one by one through ADFv2?

Comment: You can have as many functions in your function app as you need

Comment: Yes but for each function do I need to install my python libraries again? Thats the issue because it takes a lot of time to install.

Comment: you mean using pip install ??? if so, it will be shared accross your differents functions. Otherwise you can have shared code in your function app

Comment: If its shared across my other functions then its awesome. Thats what I needed.

Comment: Can you provide the answer of the question in a seperate comment so that I accept it for the benefit of others?

Comment: Just one last question if you dont mind. I have Azure function in my free trial account. Can I migrate it to my company's account (Pay as per go) where my production Azure portal is?

Comment: i dont think so. Just commit your existing code to a git repo then you can easily recreate a new function app with the same code.

Comment: my only worry is to reinstall python modules. Will it be a part of that commit?

Comment: Nope you will have to reinstall the modules and extensions. you can script this part: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47213859/4167200

Comment: Thanks Thomas. Can you please post the solution of the question as a seperate post and I will mark it as the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it is possible to execute a bunch of python files but the main constraint is that the total execution time should be less then 10min.