# azure web app service (PYTHON) failed as pip failed for azure-iothub-device-client

Tags: python, azure, azure-web-app-service

pip install requirements failed for azure-iothub-device-client==1.3.2

I tried to git myPython web app to AZURE WEB APP. My web app is running perfect in local. When I push the code to azure web app, it throws error while doing pip install requirements

> PS C:\Users\hackuser1\Desktop\Madhu\tryPythonWeb\python-docs-hello-world> git push azure master
>   
>  Counting objects: 3, done.
>   
>  Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
>   
>  Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 324 bytes | 108.00 KiB/s, done.
>   
>  Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
>   
>  remote: Updating branch 'master'.
>   
>  remote: Updating submodules.
>   
>  remote: Preparing deployment for commit id '4bce78d374'.
>   
>  remote: Generating deployment script.
>   
>  remote: Running deployment command...
>   
>  remote: Handling python deployment.
>   
>  remote: KuduSync.NET from: 'D:\home\site\repository' to: 'D:\home\site\wwwroot'
>   
>  remote: Copying file: 'requirements.txt'
>   
>  remote: Detected requirements.txt.  You can skip Python specific steps with a .skipPythonDeployment file.
>   
>  remote: Detecting Python runtime from site configuration
>   
>  remote: Detected python-2.7
>   
>  remote: Found compatible virtual environment.
>   
>  remote: Pip install requirements.
>   
>  remote: Downloading/unpacking azure-iothub-device-client==1.3.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
>   
>  remote:   Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement azure-iothub-device-client==1.3.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
>   
>  remote: Cleaning up...
>   
>  remote: No distributions at all found for azure-iothub-device-client==1.3.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
>   
>  remote: Storing debug log for failure in D:\home\pip\pip.log
>   
>  remote: An error has occurred during web site deployment.
>   
>  remote:
>   
>  remote: Error - Changes committed to remote repository but deployment to website failed.

below is the data in requirements file

> azure-iothub-device-client==1.3.2 
>   azure-iothub-service-client==1.3.2 
>   Flask==1.0.2 
>   Flask-Sijax==0.4.1

Answer (score 0):

The current version of "pip" pre-installed on Function is too old to know how to install a wheel, and you require a wheel since this one includes a C extension. See also: [Azure functions: Installing Python modules and extensions on consumption plan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43970307/azure-functions-installing-python-modules-and-extensions-on-consumption-plan/43984890#43984890)

Also, if you want to deploy with git, you might want to install your own Python and this tutorial can give some ideas:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/app-service-msi-keyvault-python#installation-on-azure