# How do I open Kudu console in Azure functions consumption plan?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, kudu

I am on an Azure Functions consumption plan, and am trying to follow the guide in this stackoverflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43984890/6700475

How can I do step 2, namely to "Open a Kudu console"? I have tried:

- Clicking "Advanced tools (Kudu)" in the portal - but get this warning: "Linux Consumption Functions are a preview offer."
- Finding the SCM page using: https://MYFUNCTION.scm.azurewebsites.net/, but this page is not available.

Is there another way to open a Kudu console, which works for a consumption plan on Azure functions?

(The reason I need this, is I have a Python Function I need to deploy to Azure functions, but it fails with this issue in the python worker, and I do not have Docker: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/issues/367)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently, we don't have support for local git deploy (kudu) for Functions on the Linux Consumption plan (and do not support zip deploy).

The only way to deploy to linux consumption apps is using [Run-From-Package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-azure-function-azure-cli-linux#deploy-the-function-app-project-to-azure).

Here is a similar [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/1173) you could refer to.