# Azure functions asked for pdftotext

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I came across with a runtime error from my Azure function:

```
Result: Failure Exception: Exception: pdftotext is not installed. It is part of xpdf or poppler-utils software suite. 
Installation on Linux: wget --no-check-certificate https://dl.xpdfreader.com/xpdf-tools-linux-4.02.tar.gz && tar -xvf xpdf-tools-linux-4.02.tar.gz && sudo cp xpdf-tools-linux-4.02/bin64/pdftotext /usr/local/bin 
Installation on MacOS: brew install xpdf 
You can find more details here: https://www.xpdfreader.com 
Stack: File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.6/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 357, in _handle__invocation_request self.__run_sync_func, invocation_id, fi.func, args) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 56, in run result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs) 
File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.6/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 542, in __run_sync_func return func(**params) File "/home/site/wwwroot/testFunction/__init__.py", line 45, in main searchResult = bootLoader.run(filePath, query) 
File "/home/site/wwwroot/testFunction/bootLoader.py", line 44, in run doc = docPrepare(filePath) File "/home/site/wwwroot/testFunction/bootLoader.py", line 19, in docPrepare converter = PDFToTextConverter(remove_numeric_tables=True, valid_languages=["en"]) File "/home/site/wwwroot/testFunction/haystack/file_converter/pdf.py", line 38, in __init__ """
Error
```

The function runs successfully on my machine since I have installed the `xpdf` locally. My questions is how to install `pdftotext` to the running environment (linux) of my function?

**ENV**

python 3.6

MAC OSX mojave

Deployed via vs code azure function extension

**UPDATE**

I visited the `https://{FunctionAppName}.scm.azurewebsites.net/`.[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Kudu Console from your function app and then you need to navigate to the www root folder and do the pip install

I have described in the last section of this [post](https://sajeetharan.com/2020/01/10/want-to-alert-your-employees-to-have-a-break-at-work-azure-function-can-help-you/)

Comment: Thanks to your suggestion. I tried to find the kudu console and saw this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56035616/how-do-i-open-kudu-console-in-azure-functions-consumption-plan). It seems kudu console is not supported for linux consumption plan. Correct my if I am wrong. Does it mean I have to upgrade my function app into another plan?

Comment: I updated the OP with the content from the site `https://{FunctionAppName}.scm.azurewebsites.net/`. Please have a look.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43970307/azure-functions-installing-python-modules-and-extensions-on-consumption-plan

Comment: I saw that post and did follow the instructions, but I cannot find the kudu console for my function. I then found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56035616/how-do-i-open-kudu-console-in-azure-functions-consumption-plan) which indicates that kudu is not available for function in consumption plan.