# Why doesn't my Node.js Typescript function app deploy properly to an app using the Linux Consumption plan?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have a simple Node.js function app that I built using Azure Functions Core Tools.  The app was built with two commands `func init` and `func new`.  The app uses TypeScript and that seems to be key--the problem I am running into does not reproduce if I use JavaScript.

When I use [curl and the zipdeploy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/deployment-zip-push) end point to deploy to a function app that I created using Linux Consumption, the single Http Trigger function in my app is not recognized.

If use curl+zipdeploy to deploy to an app in the same RG using the Premium plan, the function in my app *is* recognized.

If I use Azure Function Core Tools to deploy the .zip to the Linux Consumption app (i.e. using `az functionapp deployment source config-zip...`), the Http Trigger function *is* recognized as well.

I'm using the same .zip in all three cases.

Do I need to do something special to get a Node.js function app using TypeScript to deploy via zipdeploy to a function app using the Consumption plan?

Answer (score 0):

I have created a function app with runtime stack node.js and a Linux consumption plan.

[image]

I created a http trigger function with typescript runtimestack.
`npm install typescript ts-node @types/node` and `npx tsc --init` packages have been installed.
The function was executed successfully.
check below:

[image]

Thanks @Andrew miller for [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/deployment-zip-push?tryIt=true&source=docs#code-try-0).
First, I zipped the project folder.
I uploaded the zip folder in Azure PowerShell, and by using the command `az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g your-resource-group -n nodetype --src newtype1.zip`, I was able to deploy to the function app.

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: As I mentioned in the original post, `az functionapp deployment...` works for me as well.

But trying to post the ZIP using the /zipdeploy API does not.

Comment: by referring this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56035713/21525734)
using Linux consumption plan curl zip deploy is not possible.